# Timestamp difference in seconds

Tags: javascript, angular

I need difference of two timestamp in seconds. But when calculate it gave wrongly. How to calculate the seconds from difference of two timestamp? Thanks in advance.

Here,

```
First timestamp = 20180104113612
Second timestamp = 20180104113954
Difference = First timestamp - Second timestamp
```

It results as 342. But actually it should be 222. So please anyone help to find the difference in seconds?

Comment: how 20180104113954 - 20180104113612 is 222?

Comment: calculating the seconds between the time.

Comment: What timestamp format is it, could you please mention how you get `20180104113612`

Comment: format of timestamp is timestamp = year + '' + month + day + hour + minutes + seconds;

Comment: This is not a _timestamp_, this is a _DateTime_ (or JS _Date_)  with delimiters removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse out year, month, day, hour, minutes and seconds from your date and create a `date` object and then subtract both dates to get the difference.

```js
var firstTimestamp = 20180104113612,
    secondTimestamp = 20180104113954,
    
    getDate = (time) => {
      time = time.toString();
      var year = time.substring(0,4),
          month = time.substring(4,6),
          day = time.substring(6,8),
          hour = time.substring(8,10),
          minutes = time.substring(10,12),
          seconds = time.substring(12,14);
          return new Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds);
    },
    
    getTimeDifference = (firstTime, secondTime) => {
      return Math.floor((getDate(secondTime) - getDate(firstTime))/1000);
    };
    
console.log(getTimeDifference(firstTimestamp, secondTimestamp));
```

Comment: Thanks. I got what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let startDate = new Date();
let endDate   = new Date();
let differenceInSecond = (endDate - startDate) / 1000; //since it's originally in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to format your date in proper format something like this. "2018-01-04T11:36:12";

for formatting you can use make some function like this

```
function getFormat(dateString) {
    var txt = dateString.slice(0, 4) 
               + "-" 
               + dateString.slice(4, 6) 
               + "-" 
               +dateString.slice(6,8)
               +"T"
               +dateString.slice(8,10)
               +":"
               +dateString.slice(10,12)
               +":"
               +dateString.slice(12,14);
    return txt;
}
```

and then convert it into javascript Date object.

```
const First_timestamp = 20180104113612;
const Second_timestamp = 20180104113954;
const FirstDate = new Date(getFormat(First_timestamp.toString()));
const SecondDate = new Date(getFormat(Second_timestamp.toString()));
const TimeDiffInSeconds = (SecondDate.getTime() - FirstDate.getTime()) / 1000;
```

Comment: This also give correct value what i expected. But i could not activate the tick mark for this answer.